# What to do in Barcelona?

Tags: barcelona

I'm going to be for one week in Barcelona. Any tips of nice things to do? I don't like night clubs and such so much. I like to see curious local things, eat good food and the like. I'm not a great art appraiser, but I've been to museums that I liked. I liked musée d'Orsay in Paris and I loved the museum of science in London (althought it has less to do with art).

I also like going to places that have nice architecture and which tells me about the local history of the place.

Comment: You have no idea how much you are going to love Barcelona! If food and architecture are what you value in a city, you chose the right one to visit

Comment: I can see this is quite a popular question but I think it's far too general. Stack Exchange questions are expected to show some effort. Before you ask here you should check out sites like [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Barcelona),  [Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Barcelona), [tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g187497-c105837/Barcelona:Spain:The.Best.Sights.Of.Barcelona.html), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona#Main_sights). When you don't find what you want there then it's time to ask us here.

Comment: We try to ask questions that get specific answers - as per our [faq].  I see you've gotten an answer you like already, which is great, but really asking questions which engage polling are against the [faq] conditions, and really aren't a great fit for the stackexchange format. As such, I'm closing this question for now, and also to prevent 'me too' answers - almost everyone who has been to Spain will have been to Barcelona, and there are LOTS of restaurants, architecture and more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Barcelona is a great place to visit; it has been the object of lots of changes some twenty years ago when it hosted the Olympic Games and it has resulted in a general improvement of the area.

As you probably know, Barcelona is the town where the Catalan architect Antoni Gaudí  worked and it can show some of the best examples of his visionary form of art. You can't miss visiting [the Sagrada Familia](http://www.sagradafamilia.cat/), the expiatory temple which was recently opened for rites but which is not yet completed, or [Parque Güell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_G%C3%BCell), now a public park on a hill which he meant to become an example of integration between normal city life and art and nature. Closer to the town centre you have [Casa Milá](http://www.lapedrera.com/ca/home), better known as La Pedrera, another incredibly interesting building which demonstrates Gaudí's genius. All these places can be visited (the only free one is Parque Güell), whereas Casa Batlló must be seen from the outside unless you have arranged a special visit or event.

One more thing I would recommend to get the feeling of the place is a visit to the [Boqueria](http://www.boqueria.info/index.php?lang=es), an incredible covered food market where you can buy almost anything and where you can easily get a savoury meal for little money. It is just on [the Ramblas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Rambla,_Barcelona), a long tree-lined avenue which goes down from Plaza Catalunya to the port and which is a must-see for all tourists.

One museum which in my opinion you can do without is the Picasso Museum, particularly if you have already seen some of his paintings in other places.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a city person, but I've been to Barcelona as a 13-year old in 1998. One day that I particularly remember is when we [hiked up Montserrat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montserrat_%28mountain%29), very close to Barcelona and interesting both from a cultural and natural point of view. Should probably still be fine even if it's almost November (the picture below was apparently taken in January).

[image: Picture of Montserrat]

*Image source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Montserrat_Mountains,_Catalonia,_Spain_-_Jan_2007.jpg). Photo by DAVID ILIFF. License: CC-BY-SA 3.0*

Answer (score 5):

You have to see Sagrada Familia of course. Do the climb up to the top of the tower. See the museumy thing in the basement. Visit the little school right next door with the wavy roof.

In addition to any Olympic-y or other Gaudi things, you should walk down Las Ramblas about 10 or 11pm. Don't have a lot of money on you when you do, so you can relax and gawk at all there is to gawk at.

Eat tapas. Drink beer or cava or both. Eat more tapas. Repeat as necessary.

I also enjoyed Montjuic, the funicular up to it, and the cable car.

Answer (score 3):

Barcelona is well known of their football club. One of the best player in the world (Lionel Messi) is a Barcelona player.

Since you like architecture, you may want to visit Barcelona stadium ( Camp Nou ).The [Camp Nou Tour](http://www.fcbarcelona.com/camp-nou/museum) is only open on the non-match day.

[image]

Comment: Even if you don't like football you have to go to the Camp Nou. You can visit the stadium free. All you have to do is go a day that there is a match: 10 minutes before match end, the doors are open and nobody ask you for an entrance. You can view last 5-10 minuts of the match, and when the players go out, you can even touch the green field.

Answer (score 2):

Two things that stood out from my last visit to Barcelona in March 2011:

- Joining a laser cutting workshop at the [DHUB FAB](http://www.dhub-bcn.cat). This workshop was open to everyone and cost somewhere between 30 and 50 EUR per person for two days. There is also the [Fab Lab Barcelona](http://fablabbcn.org/), which is somehow connected.
- Walking up the mountain to the [fortress at Montjuïc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montju%C3%AFc). The view reminded me of an advertisement for a logistics company: ground vehicles, ships, and airplanes (BCN). Watching the [Port of Barcelona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_of_Barcelona) from above was fun.